# How to write a fraction $\frac{n}{m}$ in the form $\frac{1}{x}$

Tags: arithmetic

If 663 million people don't have an item in the population of 7.3 billion, then 1 in how many people don't have it? 
What is the calculation I would use? 
How could I figure this problem for myself in the future?

I'm not even sure if I picked the right tag.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: And please edit the question title, to depict what you want to ask.

**Complete ditz on math needs help** isn't a nice title to have.

Comment: I apologize for the downvotes--they are scarcely a friendly introduction to the site, are they?  Perhaps people are concerned that the title is about you rather than about your question, as @Dawny has indicated.

Comment: Yes, I was talking about myself. I am the ditz. Math is a total cipher (pun intended) for me. I am a "word" person -- an editor -- being asked to check facts. UGH.

Comment: @DeniseKoenig Not to stray off-topic, but why have you been tasked to do this? If you're an editor, you should be finding someone else to do this for you. Is there no one at your work more qualified to do this?

Comment: I've tried to give the q. a more useful title. Does it seem all right?

Comment: @AdamO  No one around to help out. Usually someone can do the math for me.

Answer (score 4):

If you write the fraction like

$$\left( \frac{\mbox{# cases}}{\mbox{# population}}\right)$$

What transformation would you apply to the numerator and denominator so that there is only 1 case in the numerator?

Comment: AdamO. I would have answered the question you asked if I knew what you were asking. The math language doesn't work for me. Sorry.

Comment: Maths, which maths?!